# ASP.NET 5: How to configure the path of logs in Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, microsoft-extensions-logging

I'm working on an MVC6 web app and I'm new to ASP.NET 5.
I can see that the Logging (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) is used at many places (eg: AccountController.cs) in ASP.NET 5 default web application template, but I couldn't figure out where to configure the path of the created log file.
Below settings are found in appsettings.json file.

```
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Verbose",
  "System": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Information"
}  }
```

Is it enough to add a parameter in this section? If yes, what is the parameter name? If no, how to do it?

Previously I used Log4Net and configurations were done inside logger.config file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ILogger is just an abstraction, you have to implement a concrete logger (log4net, serilog, ...) to log in a file.

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // Some other code 

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug().WriteTo.File("YOUR FILE PATH HERE")
            .CreateLogger();

}
```

In configure's method (using serilog here) :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

    // Some other code
}
```

[Official documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html)

Comment: Ok.. Now I understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in file logger in `ASP.NET Core`. Logging Github [repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src)

But there is a port to use `log4net` on `ASP.NET Core`. Link to [sources](https://github.com/ashimoon/dotnetliberty.AspNet.log4net) and the blog [post](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/11/09/asp-net-5-logging-with-log4net/)

Comment: What about Microsoft.Extensions.Logging namesapce and ILogger interface?

Comment: @SudeepAR its just an abstraction that you can use to build your own loggers, no concrete implementation for logging into file

Comment: Really? Forgive me if I'm wrong, what about the implementations in LoggerExtensions class inside Microsoft.Extensions.Logging namespace?

Comment: @SudeepAR they are just extension methods on ILogger interface

Comment: Ok.. Now I understood. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Use Serilog, Add file logging to ASP.NET Core apps with one line of code.

Install **Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File**

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder.AddFile("Logs/myapp-{Date}.txt");
            })
```

https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file